# Find and Replace URLs in SharePoint pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, modern-pages, 2019

We currently migrated from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2019 with modern UI pages.

The problem we're now facing is kinda special.

To bring all pages into modern UI we took a hook via SharePoint Online and migrated those pages from SharePoint Online to SharePoint on-Premise.

My problem now is, that every link on a pages comes with:

```
https://DOMAIN/sites/SITECOLLECTION/Previous_SOMENAME.aspx
```

The part `Previous_` in the pages name heads to broken links. The correct path would be:

```
https://DOMAIN/sites/SITECOLLECTION/SOMENAME.aspx.
```

Any ideas how to solve that with PowerShell or something similar?

I'd like to avoid doing it manually because there are about 200 affected pages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to “bring all pages into modern UI”? As far as I know, that’s currently not possible for SharePoint on-premise. And how did you migrate from SharePoint Online to SharePoint 2019?

It is not supported to change page URL (with PowerShell) for the time being, either SharePoint Online or on-premise.

Comment: A colleague of mine did this with a 3rd Party Tool called ShareGate. I'm currently not that familiar with this tool. Most of the times I simply use it to migrate from onPrem to online, not vice versa.